# Identify rows with missing records for a YYYYQ quarter that sits in between two quarters for which records do exist

Tags: python, pandas

This is a sample from my pandas df.

|  | plant | device | quarter | avg_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | 4962 | 939322103 | 1999Q3 | 3624000.0 |
| 16 | 4962 | 939322103 | 1999Q2 | 4407000.0 |
| 15 | 4962 | 939322103 | 1999Q1 | 5065000.0 |
| 14 | 4962 | 460981301 | 2006Q2 | 390000.0 |
| 13 | 4962 | 460981301 | 2006Q1 | 407000.0 |
| 12 | 4962 | 460981301 | 2005Q4 | 336000.0 |
| 11 | 4962 | 45839N101 | 1999Q3 | 6977000.0 |
| 10 | 4962 | **387241102** | **1999Q3** | 95000.0 |
| 9 | 4962 | **387241102** | **1999Q1** | 57000.0 |

In the row with indexes `10` and `9`, for the same device `387241102` I've got the same device reporting data for `avg_value` for `1999Q1` and `1999Q3`. The business logic states that if there is a missing data for one quarter that sits between two quarters that do have `avg_value` present, then treat this case as missing data and impute it by creating a new row for the  missing `[plant, device, quarter]` combination and copying the `avg_value` from the latest out of two quarters for the same `[plant, device, quarter]`. In this case, the copying `avg_value` from `1999Q3`

Meaning, for the case above, I'd need to create a new entry for the `1999Q2` in my pandas df like so.

|  | plant | device | quarter | avg_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 4962 | 387241102 | **1999Q2** | **95000.0** |

I'm struggling with identifying these cases with missing quarter sitting in between two that do have the data ... any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

#### Annotated code

```
# Create a period index by parsing quarter
idx = pd.PeriodIndex(df['quarter'], freq='Q')

# Set the index of dataframe to period idx and sort
df1 = df.drop('quarter', axis=1).set_index(idx).sort_index()

# Group the dataframe by [plant, device] and resample
# with quaterly frequency then use bfill to fill resampled
# NaN values with the values from latest quater
df1 = df1.groupby(['plant', 'device'], group_keys=False).resample('Q').bfill().reset_index()
```

#### Result

```
  quarter  plant     device  avg_value
0  1999Q1   4962  387241102    57000.0
1  1999Q2   4962  387241102    95000.0
2  1999Q3   4962  387241102    95000.0
3  1999Q3   4962  45839N101  6977000.0
4  2005Q4   4962  460981301   336000.0
5  2006Q1   4962  460981301   407000.0
6  2006Q2   4962  460981301   390000.0
7  1999Q1   4962  939322103  5065000.0
8  1999Q2   4962  939322103  4407000.0
9  1999Q3   4962  939322103  3624000.0
```

Comment: Thanks @Shubham, What would happen in case there are two quarters without records in between the two with data. For example, `1999Q1` and `1999Q4` have data and `1999Q2` and `1999Q3` don't? in this case I don't need any record creation and data imputation. **Only** if there is one quarter missing.

Comment: I ran your solution where the gap in quarters is 1999Q1 and 1999Q4 and unfortunately, it still resamples and creates two new records. As I mentioned in my comment above, this is not what I need. I only need the record generated when there is only **one** quarter gap between the other two. If the gap is two or more quarters, no new records should be generated. Thanks

Comment: @kuatroka Sorry for late response...Just wanted to check if your problem is solved?

Comment: Sort of... I'm using .shift() option on the [`quarter, plant]` group to identify where the difference of quarters is exactly 2 and then trying to create and insert an new row into the same df. A bit tricky, but I'm getting there

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has several functions that are very convenient to manipulate time series. So one way to do this is to index your data by plant-device-quarter, then loop over all plant-device combinations, and use pd.PeriodIndex and df.resample to get your results, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

datastr = StringIO("""plant,device,quarter,avg_value
4962,939322103,1999Q3,3624000.0
4962,939322103,1999Q2,4407000.0
4962,939322103,1999Q1,5065000.0
4962,460981301,2006Q2,390000.0
4962,460981301,2006Q1,407000.0
4962,460981301,2005Q4,336000.0
4962,45839N101,1999Q3,6977000.0
4962,387241102,1999Q3,95000.0
4962,387241102,1999Q1,57000.0
""")

df = pd.read_csv(datastr, index_col=[0,1,2]).sort_index()

def fill_quarter_gaps(sdf):
    sdf2 = sdf.reset_index(level=['plant','device'], drop=True)
    sdf2.index = pd.PeriodIndex(sdf2.index, freq='Q')
    return sdf2.resample('Q').bfill()

df.groupby(level=[0,1]).apply(fill_quarter_gaps)
```

The output will be indexed by plant-device-quarter, but you can reset the index if you want to move those variables to regular columns.

Comment: I didn't realized that someone else had answered this question by the time I posted my answer. To be honest, I like Shubham Sharma's answer more, as the code is way cleaner!

Comment: Hi @Randall, thanks for giving it go. Unfortunately, as in Shubham's case, it doesn't work for my precise case. Here is the comment I left for Shubham. ................................................. I ran your solution where the gap in quarters is 1999Q1 and 1999Q4 and unfortunately, it still resamples and creates two new records. As I mentioned in my comment above, this is not what I need. I only need the record generated when there is only **one** quarter gap between the other two. If the gap is two or more quarters, no new records should be generated. Thanks...........................